# TabActivity not starting activity when tab widget touched

Tags: android, tabactivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_uicreate_session);
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
TabSpec sessionTab = tabHost.newTabSpec("Sessions");
sessionTab.setIndicator("Sessions");
Intent i = new Intent().setClass(this, TabSessions.class);
sessionTab.setContent(i);
tabHost.addTab(sessionTab);
}
```

When I click on 'Sessions' nothing happens, no stacktrace, nothing.

I am not using fragments because I want to target devices on as low as sdk version 8.

Comment: But if that is the only tab, what do you expect to happen? I think that tab is already displayed.. try to add one more tab at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed by moving to the fragment layout.